# Calculating the polynomial features after or before centering the data?

Tags: regression, prediction, scikit-learn, standardization, polynomial

I am using `scikit-learn`. I use the following to center the predictor features:

```
X = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

I will use the following code to create the polynomial features:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly.fit_transform(X)
```

My question is regarding if I should center the data before or after creating the polynomial features. Would it matter and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polynomial fit contains intercept, it will take account the centering job. If not, it is good to center data before passing it to the model.

Here is a demo in R, where red line is the model without intercept.

```
set.seed(3)
x=runif(10)+3
y=runif(10)
fit1=lm(y~poly(x,2))
plot(x,y,ylim=c(0,1))
lines(seq(-5,5,0.01),predict(fit1,data.frame(x=seq(-5,5,0.01))))

fit2=lm(y~poly(x,2)-1)
lines(seq(-5,5,0.01),predict(fit2,data.frame(x=seq(-5,5,0.01))),col=2)
```

[image]

In addition if you use [**orthogonal polynomials**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalPolynomials.html) not only it centers for you, but also numerically stable.

Here is the demo

```
> set.seed(0)
> x=runif(100)
> colMeans(poly(x,2,raw=F))
            1             2 
 3.971433e-18 -4.330303e-18
> colMeans(poly(x,2,raw=T))
        1         2 
0.5207647 0.3434324
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit `If the polynomial fit contains intercept, it will take account the centering job`? So, sometimes we do not prefer to have the intercept? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @renakre Check the data matrix $X$ after polynomial expansion, if it contains a column that is all $1$, then it contains the intercept.

Comment: @renakre in most cases, we should fit a model with intercept. Some special cases, we want $y=0$ when $x=0$, we can force the model pass though the origin, i,e., fit a model without intercept.

Comment: It's not just a question of centering.  What about the scaling (normalization)?  Should  that be before the polynomial features are calculated or after?